# No me aparece nada al hacer render un map al state,

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Utilizo *usseEffect* y hago dos llamadas de api seguidas, se agrega correctamente al stade, pero al hacer un render map no aparece nada, la sensación es como que hace render aparece y desaparece al momento.

De pronto hay una mejor forma llamar a la api y me haga render, agradezco la ayuda.

Si hago una sola llamada al api, me funciona bien renderizando el nombre,  al llamar a la primera api:

```
const response = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=${numero}&limit=4`);
```

Sí me renderiza en la propiedad name, pero como necesito más datos, utilizo el nombre para completar el otro llamado de api y me trae muchos mas datos.

Metí todo a un state y aparece bien en componentes pero al hacer map para renderizar  no me aparece.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Pokedex() {
    //useState
    const [pokemonData, setPokemoData] = useState<any>([]);

    useEffect(() => {

        const getPokemonDinamic = async (numero?: string) => { //llamar los primeros pokemon

            const response = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=${numero}&limit=4`);

            const data: any = await response.data;

            const arra: any = data.results.map((x: any) => x.name)

            let array: any = [];
            arra.map(async (x: any) => {
                const response: any = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${x}`)
                const data: any = await response.data

                let obj: any = {
                    name: data.name,
                    img: `https://play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/xyani/${data.name}.gif`,
                    tipos: data.types.map((type: any) => { return type.type.name }),
                    hp: data.stats[0].base_stat,
                    attack: data.stats[1].base_stat,
                    defense: data.stats[2].base_stat,
                    speed: data.stats[5].base_stat,
                    id: data.id,
                }
                array.push(obj)
            })
            setPokemoData(array)
        }
        getPokemonDinamic("0")
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {
                pokemonData.length > 0 && pokemonData.map((x: any) => {
                    return (
                        <h1>{x.name}</h1>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar un log de pokemonData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas realizando algunas cosas que son innecesarias al llamar a una `API` con `axios`. Una vez que la *API* te responde, no necesitas volver a especificar `await` en el data, ya que `response` trae toda la información sin necesidad de volver a realizar algún request.

Ahora, si necesitas hacer múltiples llamadas dentro de algún ciclo o similar, trabaja con `Promise.all`, que según la **[documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)**, es una promesa "padre" que se resuelve o rechaza, cuando todas las demás promesas hijas (en este caso, cada llamada por pokémon) son resueltas o rechazadas también.

Por lo que, esto debería funcionar

```
const fullData = await Promise.all(
   names.map(async name => {
      const info = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`)

      return {
         name: info.data.name,
         img: `https://play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/xyani/${info.data.name}.gif`,
         tipos: info.data.types.map((type) => type.type.name),
         hp: info.data.stats[0].base_stat,
         attack: info.data.stats[1].base_stat,
         defense: info.data.stats[2].base_stat,
         speed: info.data.stats[5].base_stat,
         id: info.data.id
      }
   }))
```

`names` sería el nombre de cada pokémon obtenidos en la primera llamada, y por cada uno vamos recolectando la información dentro de `map`.

**[Acá](https://codesandbox.io/s/llamada-a-multiples-apis-con-promise-all-9px16?file=/src/App.js)** esta el ejemplo completo para que lo puedas revisar.

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas.

Comment: tienes toda la razón, lo solucione con Promise.all, muchas gracias.